# A combinatorial proof revised

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

I am reading a combinatorial proof for the identity
${2n\choose n}={n\choose 0}^2+{n\choose 1}^2+⋯+{n\choose n}^2$. The proof I read resorts to the concept of bit string.

Personally I don't like the introduction of bit string since it only increases complexity. My way to prove the identity is as:
${2n\choose n}$ implies choose $n$ objects from $2n$ objects. This is equivalent to partitioning $2n$ objects into $2$ equal groups, and, in the first case we choose $0$ from one group and $n$ from another; In the second case we choose $1$ from one group and $n−1$ from another; in the third case we choose $2$ from one group and $n−2$ from another. Continue this fashion, we have
${2n\choose n}={n\choose 0}{n\choose n}+{n\choose 1}{n\choose n-1}+{n\choose 2}{n\choose n−2}+⋯+{n\choose n}{n\choose 0}$.

Since ${n\choose k}={n\choose n−k}$, the formula we get above can be rewritten as
${2n\choose n}={n\choose 0}^2+{n\choose 1}^2+{n\choose 2}^2+⋯+{n\choose n}^2$.

Is my idea correct?

Comment: Yes, your proof is correct.

Comment: "Personally I don't like the introduction of bit string since it only increases complexity." : Personally, I don't know a *bit string* from a giraffe.  However, I am speculating that the intent of the problem composer is that the *bit string* analogy is not intended to be the most elegant approach to this particular problem.  Instead, I surmise that the problem composer intends that the *bit string* analogy (whatever that means) is intended to supply the Math student with **an additional weapon**, besides the Set theory approach used in your posting.  ...see next comment

Comment: It is very plausible to me, that (even at the undergraduate level), you will encounter Combinatorics problems that are easier to attack with the *bit string* weapon, rather than with the *set theory* weapon.

Comment: Your idea is okay, but your description of it left me baffled for quite some time, before finally I realized you were talking about some initial division of the $2n$ objects into two equal groups, and your "cases" describe how you are picking one side of another such division. You do need to explain the idea more clearly.